# VBA - code to show/hide columns on protected sheet getting error 1004 when I re-open file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with about 40 sheets, and on every sheet I have a button designed to show/hide columns A and B when it is clicked.  The following VBA code is assigned as a macro when the button is clicked:

```
Sub ToggleTableofContents()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not ws.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden
End Sub
```

I also need to have all these sheets protected, so I have two macros to both protect all sheets (while allowing certain permissions) and unprotect all sheets:

```
Sub ProtectAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim password As String

    password = "funpassword" 

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Columns("A:B").Locked = False
        ws.Protect password:=password, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
       
        ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        ws.EnableOutlining = True
        ws.EnableAutoFilter = True
        ws.EnablePivotTable = True
        Next ws
End Sub
```

and then:

```
Sub UnprotectAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Unprotect password:="funpassword"
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**The Problem**: The really strange thing is, when I run the ProtectAllSheets macro and then test the buttons, they work just fine to show/hide columns.  But when I close and then re-open the workbook, I get the following error: "1004 Unable to set Hidden property of the Range class".

I have enabled all my macro permissions in the Trust Center settings.  I should also note that this workbook is protected as well, but I don't see how that would affect this problem with the buttons.  This problem only occurs when I click the buttons, not when I run the protect sheets macro.  I wouldn't expect this problem to only occur when I close the protected workbook and then re-open.  If there's a problem with the code then why isn't it getting the error all the time?

Answer (score 1):

From the Worksheet.Protect method [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect):

*"In previous versions, if you apply this method with the UserInterfaceOnly argument set to True and then save the workbook, the entire worksheet (not just the interface) will be fully protected when you reopen the workbook. To re-enable the user interface protection after the workbook is opened, you must again apply this method with UserInterfaceOnly set to True."*

I'd try placing this in the ThisWorkbook object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ProtectAllSheets

End Sub
```